# Injecting custom data into Django Queryset before passing to template

Tags: python, django

What is the best way to append or inject some extra data into a Django QuerySet?

Imagine a situation where I am displaying a list of `Book`s, and I want to show the result of a special calculation on each one:

`models.py`

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

`book_list.html`

```py
{% for book in objects %}
    {{ book.name }} - {{ book.special_result }}
{% endfor %}
```

`views.py`

```py
class BookListView(ListView):
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        books = self.object_list
        
        for book in books:
            book.special_result = do_special_calculation(foo=bar)

        context['books'] = books

        return context
```

Imagine that `do_special_calculation()` method cannot be calculated in the template or as a model parameter, because it needs to have a variable `foo` passed in.

This code does not achieve the desired result of making each `book`'s `special_result` value accessible from the template, because the `book` variable is overwritten with each iteration of the `for` loop. Every solution I've come up involves basically building out a new dictionary in parallel with the QuerySet, passing that into the template, and looping through them both in the template simultaneously, causing very ugly code.

I also don't want to save the result of `do_special_calculations()` back to the database for a host of reasons (efficiency, potential stale data, can't easily save an object).

What would be the best approach to make each entry's special calculation available in the template?

Comment: `books = self.object_list` → `books = list(self.object_list)`?

Comment: Is `do_special_calculation` possibly written in SQL? If so, you can do `books = self.object_list.annotate(special_result=Func(Value(bar), function='do_special_calculation'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this by making an empty list and using `setattr()` on each entry. Here is a fixed code example:

```py
class BookListView(ListView):
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        books = self.object_list

        book_list = []
        
        for book in books:
            special_result = do_special_calculation(foo=bar)
            setattr(book, "special_result", special_result)
            book_list.append(book)

        context['books'] = book_list

        return context
```